# UIButton is not Available in app.m File

Tags: ios, uibutton, matlab

I created a **UIButton** in my **app.xib** file. I connected it to "**IBOutlet id button;**" within the **app.h** file. For some reason when I start typing in the **app.m** file "**butt...**" it doesn't find the the **id button**.
The thing is, that I have another **xib** file in this project with the same implementation where there is no problem finding in the **m** file the **id buttons** connected from the **h** file to the **xib** file.

Anyone has any idea what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the outlet using the drag to `Assistant Editor` feature, it is possible that the ivar created is `_button` in which case you either use `self.button` or `_button`.

Comment: Deepak, thanks for the reply. It doesn't work...
I keep getting an error for any way I wrote it in the m file: use of undeclared identifier 'button'.

Comment: Can you post how you've declared your button in `.h` and its usage in `.m`